# Noether's Theorem: form of infinitesimal transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

[Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) states that if the functional $J$ is an extremal and invariant under infinitesimal transformation,

$$ t' = t+ \epsilon \tau + ...,\tag{1}$$
$$ q^{\mu'} = q^{\mu} + \epsilon \zeta^{\mu} +... .\tag{2}$$

Then the following conservation law holds:

$$p_\mu \zeta^{\mu} -H \tau - F = const.\tag{3}$$

What I am curious about is the forms of $\tau$ and $\zeta$. We can find strange conservation laws for any system so long as we find the right $\tau$ and $\zeta$. For instance, a free particle will admit to energy conservation when  $ \tau = 1$ and $\zeta =0$. Also, a strange conservation for a damped oscillator can be found if $\tau =1$ and $\zeta = \frac{-bx}{2m}$.

My question is: What does the form taken by $\tau$ and $\zeta$ tell us about the system (or the laws of nature)? It seems to truly matter. Gallilean transformations ($\tau =0$, $ \zeta =t$) gives us regular old momentum conservation... Lorentz transformations do the same for relativity... But what do $\tau$ and $\zeta$ mean? What do they say? Why are they what they are?

Comment: Where did you see Noether's theorem stated in this strange looking way ?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer let us mention that (i) in a *Hamiltonian* formulation and (ii) for purely *vertical* infinitesimal quasi-symmetry transformations

$$\delta z^I~=~\epsilon \zeta^Iz^I,\tag{A}$$

meaning that OP's $\tau=0$ is assumed zero,

$$ \delta t~=~\epsilon\tau~=~0, \tag{B}$$

then the vertical generator

$$\zeta^I~=~\{z^I,Q\}\tag{C}$$

happens to be the Poisson bracket between the corresponding phase space coordinate $z^I$ and the conserved Noether charge $Q$. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE post for details.