# Nilpotency of the BRST operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem, brst

I'm styding chapter 16 of Peskin and Schroeder, in section 16.4 on the BRST symmetry, Peskin and Schroeder first checks (on page 518) that if $Q$ is the BRST symmetry operator, then $$Q^2\phi=0\tag{16.48}$$ for any field operator $\phi$, then they claim on page 519:

> Because the Lagrangian has the continuous symmetry (the BRST symmetry), the theory will have a conserved current, and the integral of the time component of this current will be a conserved charge $Q$ that commutes with $H.$ The action of $Q$ on field configurations will be just that described in the previous paragraph.

From here Peskin and Schroeder says if $Q$ now denotes the integral of the time component of the conserved charge, then $$Q^2=0\tag{16.50}.$$ My question is: why is it that the BRST symmetry operator itself being nilpotent implies that the conserved charge is also nilpotent? Why is it true that " the action of $Q$ on field configurations will be just that described in the previous paragraph"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The situation is easiest to explain in a Hamiltonian formulation. (P&S start in a Lagrangian formulation, but state on top of p. 519 that one should transcribe their formulas into the Hamiltonian language.) Then the infinitesimal BRST variation $\delta$ is given by $$\delta ~=~ \epsilon [Q,\cdot],$$
   where $Q$ is the Grassmann-odd BRST operator, $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal Grassmann-odd parameter, and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is a [super-commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra).
2. The BRST operator $Q$ is also the Noether charge for the BRST symmetry, i.e. $Q$ is the BRST charge, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69277/2451).
3. Ref. 1 shows that given a gauge symmetry, there exists a Grassmann-odd Hermitian nilpotent BRST operator $Q^2=0$ (of ghost-number 1), and a (possibly BRST-improved) Grassmann-even Hermitian Hamiltonian operator $H$ (of ghost-number 0) that commutes with $Q$.

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; Chapter 9.