# Show that the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector is conserved using poisson brackets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

(I realise [similar Phys.SE questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runge-lenz-vector) already exist but there is no answer with the Poisson bracket notation, I'll take this down if someone lets me know I should have commented in the existing question.)

I am trying to show that the Poisson bracket between the Hamiltonian and the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector vanishes, i.e.

$$\left\{H,A\right\}_{PB}=0$$

where $\vec{A} = \left(p \times L\right) - m k\cdot \hat{r}$, and the Hamiltonian is for an orbit is given by, 
$$H = \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{k}{r}$$

I have been trying to use tensor notation to write out the cross product term and the fundamental Poisson brackets but am not having any luck.

Comment: The second term is incorrect. It should be  constant times the unit vector in the radial direction. I hope that fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant to show, I'm not sure how to illustrate the r unit vector with the formatting options.

Comment: The proof of $\{A^i,H\}_{PB}=0$ is essentially done in pt. 1 - 6 of my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18843/2451).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall $A^2 = m^2k^2+2mEL^2$. We can first prove the magnutude is constant:

$$[A^2,H] = [m^2k^2+2mEL^2,H] = [2mEL^2,H]$$

$$ [A^2,H] = 4mEL[L,H] = 4mEL \dot{L} $$

Since $\dot{L} = 0 $, this implies $\dot{A} = 0$. Not we jus need to show the components are constant. Notice:

$$\vec{A} = <yL_z-mk,xL_z-mk,0>$$

Thus $A_x = A_x(y)$ and $A_y=A_y(x)$. Since $A_x^2+A_y^2= constant$ and each are functions of different variables, each must be constant.

Comment: Why does this hold: "since each are functions of different variables, each must be constant?"