# Showing The Laplace–Runge–Lenz vector (per unit mass) is constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

Given an inverse square law $\ddot{\vec{r}}=-\frac{\mu}{r^2}\hat{r}$, I define the Angular momentum per unit mass as $\vec{H}=\vec{r}\times\dot{\vec{r}}$. Showing it's constant is strightfoward. Then I defined the Laplace–Runge–Lenz vector per unit mass

> $\vec{c}=\dot{\vec{r}}\times\vec{H}-\mu\hat{r}$

I think (yet not sure) this is the normal one scaled down by $m^2$. I now try to take the derivative and get

$\frac{d\vec{c}}{dt}=\ddot{\vec{r}}\times\vec{H}+\dot{\vec{r}}\times\dot{\vec{H}}-\mu\dot{\hat{r}}=\ddot{\vec{r}}\times\vec{H}-\mu\dot{\hat{r}}=-\frac{\mu}{r^2}\hat{r}\times\vec{H}-\mu\dot{\hat{r}}$

I'm not sure how to get to $0$. I thought of substituting $\vec{H}$'s definition and using a triple cross identity but that wont yield anything.

Comment: This looks like homework, so just a hint: Start with $\vec r = r \hat r$. What is it's time derivative? To answer that, you'll need to answer the auxiliary question, what is the time derivative of $\hat r$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18088/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic the maths there is over the top for me and it doesn't revole around the one per unit mass.

Comment: @David $\dot{\hat{r}}=\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$ so $\dot{\vec{r}}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$ but what does that give me?

Comment: @Theorem - Use that to calculate $\vec H$ and then $\hat r \times \vec H$. Everything will cancel.

Comment: Alright I got it thanks! and is there no way in which you don't use $\theta$-vectors? Seems like an overkill...

Comment: See [Show that the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector is conserved using poisson brackets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109515)