# Physical interpretation of the symmetry for the Runge-Lenz vector

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, noethers-theorem, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

In the post [What symmetry causes the Runge-Lenz vector to be conserved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18088/), and based on the results of https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5001, it was it was discussed that the Runge-Lenz vector is the conserved charge of the on-shell symmetry $\delta\vec{r}=\vec{\epsilon}\times\vec{L}$. However, I don't understand the physical significance of this transformation. How could've someone guessed this symmetry before hand?

Some ideas:

1. $\vec{L}\mapsto\vec{L}+\vec{\epsilon}\times\vec{L}$ is an infinitesimal rotation of $\vec{L}$. Does this help?
2. The symmetry above is only a symmetry when the equations of motion are satisfied.
3. Problem D of section 1.1. in P. Ramond, Field Theory: A Modern Primer. Westview Press, 1990. suggests that the interpretation has something to do with the fact that Newtonian orbits do not precess.

Comment: You have understood but were disappointed by [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Runge–Lenz_vector#Conservation_and_symmetry)?

Comment: Actually, I didn't give it the relevance it deserved! Thanks for pointing me to this. I will try and see whether after understanding that my question will be answered.