# Connection between Poisson bracket and Anti-commutator?

Tags: commutator, poisson-brackets, anticommutator

Canonical quantization promotes Poisson brackets in classical mechanics to commutators in quantum mechanics. Is there any classical counterpart similar to the Poisson bracket for the anticommutator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, in classical Hamiltonian formalism, the phase space is a [supermanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold) with a [super-Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_superalgebra) $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{SPB}$. The super-Poisson bracket corresponds to a [super-commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) $\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\cdot,\cdot]_{SC}$ upon quantization. The super-commutator is a commutator (an anticommutator) in the Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd) sector, respectively.

See also my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/282321/2451).

Comment: As a person who just started learning QFT, are there some gentle introductions to supersymmetry such that I can understand your answer?