# How do fermionic operators transform?

Tags: fermions, commutator, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator, superalgebra

In quantum mechanics, if we have an operator $\Omega$, then under the transformation $T$, with infinitesimal generator $G$ (i.e. $T(\epsilon)=1-i\epsilon G + \ldots$), then operator transforms as
$$\Omega\rightarrow T^\dagger\Omega T,$$
so, infinitesimally,
$$\delta\Omega = T^\dagger\Omega T-\Omega$$
$$=(1+i\epsilon G)\Omega(1-i\epsilon G)-\Omega$$
$$=i\epsilon[G,\Omega],$$
to first order.

Now what happens if, in QFT language, $\Omega$ is a fermionic operator? I am looking at BRST symmetry, in particular, on page 19 [here](https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f1989820784.pdf) [1], it reads

> for a general field dependent function $\Phi$,
> $$\delta_B\Phi=i\theta[Q_B, \Phi]_\pm,$$
> where $Q_B$ is the conserved Noether charge associated with the BRST symmetry, $[ , ]_− = [ , ]$ and
> $[ , ]_+ = \{ , \}$, and the sign being minus/plus according as Φ is bosonic/fermionic.

Since $\Phi$ is fermionic, the anticommutator is chosen. The anticommutator is used everywhere else I look, e.g. page 74 [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk//user/rar31/LectureNotes.pdf) [2].

However, I do not understand how the standard quantum mechanical argument above breaks down if $\Omega$ is a fermionic operator. Why should $\delta \Omega$ be different depending on the bosonic/fermionic nature of $\Omega$?

---

[1] BRST quantization and string theory spectra - Bram M. Wouters

[2] String Theory - R. A. Reid-Edwards

Comment: Are $G$ and $\epsilon$ Grassmann-even or Grassmann-odd?

Comment: @Qmechanic I think I have some confusion here - I don't see why the derivation shown should depend on the Grassman-parity of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing breaks down per se. It is just that we have to use [supernumbers](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber) to mathematically describe fermions. The introduction of Grassmann-odd variables has several implication:

- At the classical level, the Poisson-bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$ is replaced by [super-Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_superalgebra) $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{SPB}$.
- At the quantum level, the commutator $[\cdot,\cdot]_C$ is replaced by [supercommutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) $[\cdot,\cdot]_{SC}$.
- The [correspondence principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) $[\cdot,\cdot]_{SC}=i\hbar\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{SPB}+{\cal O}(\hbar^2)$ between classical and quantum mechanics still holds.
- In the [Hamiltonian version of Noether's theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451), the relationship between conserved quantity $Q$ and infinitesimal symmetry $\delta~=~-\epsilon\{Q,\cdot\}_{SPB}$ still holds. Here the infinitesimal variation $\delta$ is Grassmann-even while $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter of same Grassmann-parity as $Q$.
- For operators, we calculate
  $$ \delta\Phi ~=~(1+i\epsilon Q)\Phi (1-i\epsilon Q)-\Phi~=~i[\epsilon Q,\Phi]_{SC}~=~i\epsilon [Q,\Phi]_{SC}.$$

For more information, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232382/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: We always get the supercommutator to begin with.

Comment: I see - that edit clears up my confusion. One last thing - the other answer to this question talks about the problem that Grassmann numbers don't have a notion of magnitude. Does this not effect the idea of $\epsilon$ being infinitesimal?

Comment: It depends on how one defines infinitesimal. One may argue that Grassmann-odd supernumbers are automatic infinitesimal since they square to zero.

Comment: it has also occurred to me - how do we know that the BRST transformation is going to transform as $T^\dagger \Phi T = (1+i\epsilon Q)\Phi(1-i\epsilon Q)$ for some $T$, or equivalently $Q$? I gather that in most cases (e.g. translations), we can notice that the transformation on the operators is equivalent to the active transformation of the states - but in this case, how do we know that the operator transformation has an equivalent state transformation?

Comment: Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: If a (possibly finite) symmetry operation $U$ transforms a state $|{\rm ket}'\rangle:=U|{\rm ket}\rangle$, then an operator $A$ transforms via a similarity transformation $A'=UAU^{-1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112474/discussion-between-awsomeguy-and-qmechanic).

Answer (score 0):

Your first formula $\Omega\to T^{-1} \Omega T$ describes a *finite* transformation. The commutator comes from taking the limit $T(\epsilon)= 1-i\epsilon G+\ldots$ as $\epsilon$  becomes small. There is *no such thing* as a finite supertransformation as a Grassmann parameter has no notion of being big or small. Consequently  there is no super-analogue of  $T^{-1} \Omega T$.

Comment: In that case - what does it mean to say $Q$ generates the BRST transformation? And how does one show that $\delta \Phi= i\epsilon\{Q, \Phi\}$?

Comment: Or do we just define $Q$ as the conserved charge? In which case I still cannot see why $\delta \Phi = i\epsilon\{Q,\Phi\}$

Comment: If Grassman parameters have no notion of magnitude, how can $\epsilon$ be infinitesimal?

Comment: It's just a definition. It's not derived from anywhere. It's *inspired* by  Elie Cartan's exterior derivative and its graded-derivation property.

Comment: So $Q$ is defined so that $\delta \Phi = i\epsilon (Q\Phi + \Phi Q)$?