# When does the spinor need to be in a Grassmann variable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, fermions, spinors, grassmann-numbers

Follow the closed question [When does the spinor need to be in a grassmann variable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764491/310987)

--

Does the spinor in the spinor representation of the space-time symmetry

1. Lorentz space-time symmetry, like $so(1,d)$ or $spin(1,d)$
2. Euclidean space-time symmetry, like $so(1+d)$ or $spin(1+d)$

necessarily need to be in a Grassmann variable? So $\psi \eta = -\eta \psi$ for Grassmann variable $\psi$ and $\eta$?

Comment: The 2-spinors used in spinor representation of spacetime symmetry are grassmann even. The spinors used in qft of fermionic fields uses grassmann odd numbers because of spin-statistics / pauli-exclusion principle

Answer (score 1):

1. When considering an equation that is linear in $\psi$ (such as, e.g. the transformation rule for a spinor representation), it becomes agnostic to whether we treat $\psi$ as Grassmann-odd or Grassmann-even.
2. A physical spinor field $\psi$ is Grassmann-odd in an interacting relativistic theory, cf. the [spin-statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem).
3. For more information, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723903/2451) related Phys.SE post.