# About integration measure in the completeness formula of coherent state

Tags: conventions, notation, integration, complex-numbers

In Negele's book "quantum many-particle systems", the completeness formula for coherent state is 
$$\int {\frac{{d{\phi ^*}d\phi }}{{2\pi i}}{e^{ - {\phi ^*}\phi }}} \left| \phi  \right\rangle \left\langle \phi  \right| = I\tag{1}$$
and it says the integration measure is 
$$\frac{{d{\phi ^*}d\phi }}{{2\pi i}} = \frac{{d\left( {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \phi } \right)d\left( {{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \phi } \right)}}{\pi }.\tag{2}$$
How to understand this integration measure equality?

As I understand, If I view $\phi=x+iy$, then $${d\left( {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \phi } \right)d\left( {{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} \phi } \right)}=dxdy.\tag{3}$$ But

$$d{\phi ^*}d\phi  = \left( {dx - idy} \right)\left( {dx + idy} \right) = d{x^2} + d{y^2}\tag{4}$$

I am pretty sure this understanding is wrong. What is the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning OP's last formula (4): Recall that there is an implicitly written antisymmetric wedge $\wedge$ in the integral measure. Therefore OP's last equality sign should read 
 $$( \mathrm{d}x - i\mathrm{d}y )\wedge ( \mathrm{d}x + i\mathrm{d}y ) ~=~ 2i\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y. \tag{4'}$$
See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308929/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 2):

This alternative derivation (without Grassman algebra) uses the transformation rule for integrals. We have an integral over $\mathbb {R}^2$ with the measure $dx\ dy $ (I dont care about $\pi$). We consider a change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto (z, z*):=(x+iy, x-iy) $
This is a diffeomprphism onto its image. (A subset of $\mathbb {C}^2$ seen as a 4d real vectorspace) . The Jacobian is $$ J=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 1 & -i \end {pmatrix}$$. The "absolute value" (for real and complex part individually)
 of the determinant is $2i$, the factor we need.

Comment: Why should one take the absolute value of the Jacobian for real and imaginary part individually? Seems arbitrary.

Comment: It is arbitrary. The normal change of variables formula is not really suited for dealing with complex domains. I assume to make this mathematically precise one would have to consider real and imaginary parts of the measure separatly and the domains as actually real.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to explain where that $\pi$ in eq(2) comes from:$$\begin{aligned}\int\left(\phi^{*}\right)^{n}\phi^{m}e^{-|\phi|^{2}}d\text{Re}\phi d\text{Im}\phi & =\int_{0}^{\infty}|\phi|^{n+m+1}e^{-|\phi|^{2}}d|\phi|\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(m-n)\theta}d\theta\\
 & =\pi n!\delta_{nm}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|d\text{Re}\phi d\text{Im}\phi=\sum_{n}|n\rangle\langle n|=1
$$
So actually the coherent state is over-complete and $\pi$ here is helping coherent state to disguise as a complete one. For more information one may refer to Sec2.4 of Quantum optics by Scully and Zubairy.
By the way as illustrated by Adomas Baliuka and Qmechanic♦, the relation of the coefficients in eq(1)&(2) is clear. They two arrive at the same end by different means because the appearance of the Jacobian is a natural property of the wedge product.