Integration over the complex plane and the completeness relation of the coherent states
I am studying some of the properties of coherent states using the book "Introductory Quantum Optics" by C. Gerry & L. Knight. (C. Gerry & L. Knight, Chapter 3, Section 5) And when I check the completeness relation for the coherent states the authors uses a surface integral in the complex plane for this and defines de differential of the integral in this way
$$d^2 \alpha = dRe(\alpha)dIm(\alpha)$$
I have never seen this kind of differential and I don't understand from where this differential can be obtained or defined and what is the meaning of this particular kind of integration.
Also in equation (3.66) we use one of the integral representations of kronecker delta but I don't know how to deduce this expression and I have been researching about the procedure to get that expression but I couldn't find anything about it.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308929/2451
