# How to take derivative with respect to Lagrangian of complex field?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, differentiation, complex-numbers, variational-calculus

Basics: The Lagrangian in field theory was written as 
$$\frac{\partial \mathfrak{L}}{\partial \varphi}=\partial_\mu(\frac{\partial\mathfrak{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\varphi)})$$.

Question 1:

Is $\partial_\mu\varphi=(\partial_t+\partial_x)\varphi$ now a vector/tensor, or still a single variable?

Question 2:

Further, is there any difference between 
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial (\partial_\mu\varphi) }{\partial (\partial_\mu \varphi)}$ 
(which equals to $1$ I suppose) and 
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial (\partial^\mu\varphi) }{\partial (\partial_\mu \varphi)}$?

Question 3:

How to take derivative with respect to complex field?
i.e. 
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial (\partial_\mu\varphi^\dagger) }{\partial (\partial_\mu \varphi)}$ 
, 
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial (\partial^\mu\varphi^\dagger) }{\partial (\partial_\mu \varphi)}$ 
and 
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial \varphi^\dagger}{\partial\varphi}$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong on this, guys, and take this answer with a grain of salt until verified by someone more experienced.

For a scalar field $\phi$ in flat space,

Question 1: The derivative of a scalar field is a vector, which we can see because we pick up an index $\mu$ when we operate $\partial_\mu$ on $\phi$. This is like the gradient of a scalar field in vector calculus, which is a vector.

Question 2: $$\frac{\partial(\partial^\mu\phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}= \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(\partial^\mu\phi)=\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)=g^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}=g^{\mu\nu}\delta_\nu^\mu=g^{\mu\mu}$$

Question 3: Treat the conjugate field as independent from the field. That is, the partial derivatives you have provided as examples are all zero.

Comment: Your indices don't add up here

Comment: How so? The LHS has two upstairs indices, since the $\mu$ that is downstairs is in the 'denominator.'

Comment: As in $g^{\mu\mu}$ doesn't make sense in index notation

Comment: I think the math checks out, but perhaps the starting point is not meaningful in the first place. Perhaps $g^{\mu\mu}$ correspond to the diagonal elements of the metric?