# Verifying equations of motion of Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

Given the following Lagrangian of a scalar field
$$
L = +i \psi^*\partial_t\psi - \frac{1}{2m} \nabla \psi^* \cdot \nabla \psi,
$$
I want to compute the equation(s) of motion. First by varying wrt $\psi^*$ and then wrt $\psi$.

First I say 
 $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi^{*}} = + i\partial_t\psi$$ 
and $$\partial_{\mu} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu} \psi^*)}) =  \partial_{t} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{t} \psi^*)}) + \nabla(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\nabla \psi^*)}) = 0 - \frac{1}{2m}\nabla^2 \psi. $$
By Euler -Lagrange I get

$$
i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = - \frac{1}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi.
$$

Now if I do the same but vary to $\psi$ instead of $\psi^*$, I get
$$
i \psi^* = +\frac{1}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi^{*},
$$
as equation of motion. The only main difference is that  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi} = 0.$$

Could someone verify if the answers are correct please?

The last equation is **not** a typo.But something feels weird, therefore I'd appreciate a verification. '

EDIT: Solved, my mistake was that I only considered $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{t} \psi)}) = i \psi^*$, instead of  $\partial_{t} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{t} \psi)}) = i \frac{\partial \psi^{*}}{\partial t}$.

Comment: you should show a little more effort in your exercise or at least show us your thought process behind these equations

Comment: okay, give me a few minutes

Comment: Okay, i added some details in my thought process.

Comment: HINT:  Your variation with respect to $\psi$ is not in fact correct.  Take a careful look at where that $i \psi^*$ term came from.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  the $i\psi^*$ came from deriving wrt $\partial_t \psi$.  But I really do not see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The term $\partial L/\partial (\partial_{t} \psi)$ doesn't appear in the equations of motion for $\psi$, at least not directly.

Comment: ahhhhhh, very stupid. It should have been $\partial_t (\partial L / \partial(\partial_t \psi))$

Comment: This Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\psi,\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi,\overset{\:\:\centerdot}{\psi},\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}},\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}}, \overset{\!\centerdot}{\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}}}\right)=\mathrm i\hbar\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}}\overset{\:\:\centerdot}{\psi}\!\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi\!\boldsymbol{\cdot}\!\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}} \!\boldsymbol{-}\!V\psi\psi^{\boldsymbol{*}}
$$....

Comment: ...is one  for the Schroedinger equation
$$i\hbar \overset{\:\:\centerdot}{\psi}\:\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi\:\:\boldsymbol{-}V\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)\psi\,  \boldsymbol{=} 0$$
See therein [Why treat complex scalar field and its complex conjugate as two different fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89002/why-treat-complex-scalar-field-and-its-complex-conjugate-as-two-different-fields/487935#487935).