# Treat complex conjugate variables as independent while differentiatingg

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers

In the book "The oxford solid state basics", solutions book, question 6.2.a we can see the following derivation.

[image: some derivation]

The marked statement says that a complex scalar and its conjugate can be treated as independent/separate variables when differentiating one with respect to the other (and thus the result will be 0)

Why is that?
Is there a physical logic behind it? Some approximation?
Is it mathematically correct?
Is more context needed?

There is a somewhat similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89002/why-treat-complex-scalar-field-and-its-complex-conjugate-as-two-different-fields?rq=1).
The problem is that the question is articulated as a phenomenon of QFT which makes it much harder to understand the question and the answers.
I believe that my question here is much more basic and I want to understand if it is a physical assumption or a complex analysis question (and thus belongs to math exchange).

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/660391/2451

Comment: I have flagged this for merger with your other post, since they are exact duplicates and both having upvoted answers.