# Why is there a minus in the Gauge Field Lagrangian kinetic term?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, conventions

For vector Gauge fields we usually write the kinetic term:

$$ \mathcal{L} ~=~ - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

while for matter fields e.g. for a real scalar:

$$ \mathcal{L} ~=~ \frac{1}{2} D_\mu \phi D^\mu \phi $$

with Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$.  Why is the sign different for the two and what physical difference does it make? Is it only the relative sign important or the absolute one?

Comment: Use $\mathcal L$ to calculate $H$, and you'll see that the signs are important (so that $H\ge 0$).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I can do the calculation, but could you help me understand what makes the vector bosons fundamentally different from the scalars regarding the sign?

Comment: There is nothing fundamental. It is just a convention: had we used the mostly minus metric there would be no sign difference.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87342/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic a duplicate indeed. thanks for finding!