# $1/4$ coefficient in QED Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, classical-electrodynamics

What is the reason 1/4 coefficient in the tensor multiplication of the electromagnetic field strength?
$$\mathscr{L} = -\, \frac{1}{4} \, F_{\mu \nu} \, F^{\mu \nu}. \tag{1}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the origin of the factor of −1/4 in the Maxwell Lagrangian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87342/2451)

Answer (score 2):

It's a convention, to simplify some calculations.  You could add an arbitrary factor.  In SI units for example: $$\mathscr{L}_{\text{EM}} = -\: \frac{1}{4 \mu_0} \, F_{\mu \nu} \, F^{\mu \nu}. \tag{1}$$
However, to recover the *non-homogeneous* Maxwell equation: $\partial_{\mu} \, F^{\mu \nu} = \mu_0 \, J^{\nu}$, you need the $-\, \frac{1}{4}$ factor.

Also, you could write the following:
$$-\: \frac{1}{4} \, F_{\mu \nu} \, F^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} (\, E^2 - B^2), \tag{2}$$
which is similar to the classical mechanical expression $L = K - U = \frac{1}{2} \, m v^2 - U$.

Comment: In the inhomogeneous case you could also drop the 1/4, but the interaction becomes $2A\cdot J$ instead of just $A\cdot J$.

Comment: If you also put $\epsilon_0 $ then you find the correct energy from the Noether theorem.