# Noether's theorem and translations

Tags: symmetry, noethers-theorem

I'm a bit confused about Noether's theorem (or about calculus of variations in general) when it comes to the translational symmetry $x^\mu\mapsto {x'}^\mu=x^\mu-a^\mu$. My professor just wrote that if the Lagrangian density depends on $\phi$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$ only, then it transforms like

$$
\tag{1}\mathcal L\mapsto\mathcal L'=\mathcal L+a^\mu\partial_\mu\mathcal L=\mathcal L+a^\mu\partial_\nu({\delta^\nu}_\mu\mathcal L)
$$

I don't understand why this is the case and how it is derived.

This is what I have tried so far to derive it:

Let's make the "infinitesimal" translation $x^\mu\mapsto x^\mu-a^\mu$ a bit more concrete by introducing a parameter $\alpha$ that is meant in the limit $\alpha\to 0$. The translation is then $x^\mu\mapsto x^\mu-\alpha\,a^\mu$, so we have

\begin{align}
\frac{d\phi}{d\alpha}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial {x'}^\mu}\frac{\partial{x'}^\mu}{\partial\alpha} = -a^\mu\partial_\mu\phi
\end{align}

For $\mathcal L$, I got:

\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathcal L}{d\alpha} & =\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha} + \frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\frac{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}{\partial\alpha} \\
& = \frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha} + \frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\partial_\nu\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha} \\
& = -a^\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi}\partial_\mu\phi+\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\partial_\nu\partial_\mu\phi\right)\\
& = -a^\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi}\partial_\mu\phi+\partial_\nu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\partial_\mu\phi\right)-\left(\partial_\nu\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\right)\partial_\mu\phi\right)\\
& = -a^\mu\left(\partial_\nu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\partial_\mu\phi\right)+\underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi}-\partial_\nu\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\right)}_{=0}\partial_\mu\phi\right)\\
& = -a^\mu\partial_\nu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\phi)}\partial_\mu\phi\right)
\end{align}

The last term in the brackets is something else than the last term in the brackets in $(1)$. It looks more like the first part of the Noether current $j^\mu=\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\Delta\phi-\mathcal J^\mu$. However, it should be the second part, the $\mathcal J^\mu$, which is defined as the variation of $\mathcal L$ under the symmetry: $\mathcal L\mapsto\mathcal L+\epsilon\partial_\mu\mathcal J^\mu$.

What's the problem here?

Comment: This question (v1) is essentially a field theoretic version of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) Phys.SE question for point mechanics.

Comment: The Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ can be viewed as a function of $x$ as $\mathcal{L}_{\phi}(x)=\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(x))$ for a *given* field $\phi$.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~templier/junior/The-Noether-theorems.pdf). I recomend understanding really really good this aspect since most of modern physics is based on QFT.

Comment: @Dominik I know. I'm not sure how that answers my question.

Comment: @bass its just a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)...

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_{\phi}(x+\alpha a)=\mathcal{L}_{\phi}(x)+\alpha a^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L}_{\phi})(x)+\mathcal{O}(\alpha^{2})$.

Comment: @Dominik thanks, I get it now. I was just confused by the $\delta^\mu_\nu$ in the last step of $\mathcal L(x+a)\approx\mathcal L(x)+a^\mu\partial_\mu\mathcal L=\mathcal L(x)+a^\nu\partial_\mu(\delta^\mu_\nu\mathcal L)$.