# Conservation of energy for a class of Lagrangians with explicit time dependence

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, time, symmetry, noethers-theorem

I have read in my book that if $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0$, then the quantity $ L-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \dot{q} $ is conserved, and we call it the energy of the system.

But if this is the energy of the system there is something I misunderstand with the fact that adding a term like $\frac{d}{dt} f(q,t)$ doesn't change the equations of motion.

Indeed, we could write :

$$L'=L+\alpha t$$

And $L'$ and $L$ describe the same physics of the system because $t$ can be written as $\frac{d (\frac{t^2}{2})}{dt} $.

This second lagrangian $L'$ explicitly depends on time and then the energy is not conserved, if we do the calculation we would have this equality :

$$ L'-\frac{\partial L'}{\partial \dot{q}} \dot{q}=\alpha t+b$$

So it looks like the energy is not conserved in time for the new lagrangian.

So there is something I misunderstand...

Comment: $b$ is conserved and that is defined as the energy. The LHS is not the energy, since $L'$ does not satisfy to the condition. This is a special case of Noether's theorem.

Comment: What do you call "LHS" ? Im a beginner in lagrangian mechanics.
If $b$ is not the energy, how can we define it in a general case ? In the book I read they define the energy as $-L+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{q}$ so they are wrong in a general case ?

Answer (score 1):

1. No explicit time dependence of the Lagrangian is just a simplifying sufficient condition for [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). It is not necessary. Recall that Noether's Theorem (in its original form) concerns a *quasi-symmetry* of the action $S$, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) Phys.SE answer.
2. If the Lagrangian is of the form
   $$\tag{1} L(q,\dot{q},t)~=~ L_0(q,\dot{q}) +\frac{dF(q,t)}{dt},$$
   where $L_0(q,\dot{q})$ has no explicit time dependence, then a notion of energy is 
   $$\tag{2}  \dot{q}^i\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{q}^i }-L_0.$$
   It is possible to view the energy (2) as a Noether charge associated with time translations by modifying the techniques of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) Phys.SE post.