# What are the conserved quantities in a classical field?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I'm completely new to this. I was trying to derive the conserved current of the following Lagrangian density:
$$
\mathcal L(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi + \mathcal L_{\text{int}}(\phi)
$$
If we:
$$
x^\mu \to x^\mu + \delta x^\mu
$$
$$
\phi(x^\mu + \delta x^\mu) \approx \phi + \delta x^\lambda \partial_\lambda\phi
$$
$$
\mathcal L_{\text{int}}(\phi + \delta x^\mu \partial_\mu\phi) \approx \mathcal L_{\text{int}} + \delta x^\lambda\frac{\partial \mathcal L_{\text{int}}}{\partial(\partial_\lambda \phi)} = \mathcal L_{\text{int}}
$$
Hence we get (to first order):
$$
\mathcal L(\phi + \delta \phi) \approx \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi + \mathcal L_{\text{int}}(\phi) + \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu(\delta x^\lambda \partial_\lambda\phi) 
$$
$$
\mathcal L(\phi + \delta \phi)  = \mathcal L(\phi) + \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu(\delta x^\lambda \partial_\lambda\phi)
$$

Finding the action:
$$
S[\mathcal L(\phi + \delta \phi)] = S[\mathcal L(\phi)] + \int d^4 x\; \left [ \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu(\delta x^\lambda \partial_\lambda\phi) \right ]
$$
Setting the variation of S to zero:
$$
\delta S[\mathcal L] = \int d^4 x\; \left [ \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu(\delta x^\lambda \partial_\lambda\phi) \right ] = 0
$$
But I do not know if my reasoning is good? Should the conserved current be a vector? And, could you made this current independent of $\delta x^\lambda$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301847/2451 and links therein.