# How Conservation of energy due to time symmetry appears in lever system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, symmetry

Consider a lever or a machine which acts as a force multiplier in that case we do the same work or create a greater force by moving a smaller distance how the idea of conservation of energy due to time symmetry appear in this case?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451

Answer (score 0):

Work is force times distance, in this case you apply a small force over a large distance, while on the other side a large force is applied over a smaller distance. But the amount of work, the product of force and distance, is the same on both sides.