# Getting a Conserved Quantity from a Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, symmetry, noethers-theorem

So I've been messing around with the implications of Noether's theorem, and though I conceptually get what it's saying, I'm having a hard time actually using it to retrieve a conserved quantity from a given Lagrangian. Procedurally if someone could show how to go about finding energy conservation from a generalized Lagrangian, and then using that procedure explain how I might derive the conservation of parity or charge from it, it'd do me a lot of help.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that our Lagrangian depends on quantities $t, q$ and $\dot{q}$. We start by finding the change in Lagrangian
$$ \frac{d}{dt}L = \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}  \frac{dt}{dt}+  \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}  \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \frac{d \dot{q}}{dt}$$
By adding and subtracting
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\bigg) \frac{dq}{dt}$$
Now the change in Lagrangian can be written as 
$$\frac{d}{dt}L = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\frac{d q}{dt} \bigg) $$
Hence we define 
$$ H =\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\frac{d q}{dt} -L$$ 
as the Hamiltonian which is conserved. Noether's Theorem has a similar approach.