# Conservations for time or space translational invariance, why $\delta L\vert_{\text{time trans}}\neq 0$? but $\delta L\vert_{\text{space trans}}= 0$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

### To summarize my question first,

Given a classical mechanics Lagrangian,
$L=L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)$,

1. Why the conservation law  for time $t$-translational invariant system,  under time variance $\delta t$,
   has $\delta L\vert_{\text{time trans}} \neq 0$  in general?
   But why the conservation law  for space $x$-translational invariant system,  under space variance $\delta x$,
   has $\delta L\vert_{\text{space trans}}  = 0$ in general?
2. Why for deriving the conservation laws for time $t$-translational invariant system,
   we directly apply $\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0$?
   But why for deriving the conservation laws for space $x$-translational invariant system,
   we do not directly apply $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$ but use $\delta \dot{x}=\delta \ddot{x}=\dots=0$ to derive $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$?

**PLEASE try to answer my question in a fundamental level, instead of the technical level. But please be explicit in your answer.**

p.s. I tried to derive the Conservation Laws myself based on my own logic, but you can compare with Chapter 7.9 of Thornton-Marion Edition 5.

---

### Details

**1. Energy conservation**:

If the system is time translational invariant, given a classical mechanics Lagrangian,
$L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)$, I follow @Richard Myers previous advice,
let us think about the process that we redefine a new $L'$ such that
we assign $L(x(t+\delta t), \dot{x}(t+\delta t); t+\delta t)$ at the time $t+\delta t$ to the new $L'$ at the time $t$:
$$
L'(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t) =L(x(t+\delta t), \dot{x}(t+\delta t); t+\delta t)
\equiv L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta x
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x}
+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \delta t 
$$
$$
=L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)
+ (\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\dot{x}  
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\ddot{x}   
+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}) \delta t 
$$
If the system is time translational invariant, we interpret that the $L$ has no explicit time-dependent but only implicit time dependent (but why?)
so $$\boxed{\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0},$$ we plug in to get
$$
\Rightarrow
\boxed{\delta L\vert_{\text{time translation}}  \equiv L'(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)-L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)
=(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\dot{x}  
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\ddot{x}   
) \delta t}
$$
*My question* is that WHY this quantity is nonzero in general?
$$
\boxed{\delta L\vert_{\text{time translation}} \neq 0}
$$
so we cannot claim (why not?)
$(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\dot{x}  
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\ddot{x})=0$,
but we use the Lagrangian Eq Of Motion (EOM) (for time implicit dependent $L$) to write
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}= \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}$,so
$$
\Rightarrow
{\delta L\vert_{\text{time translation}}  
=(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{x}  
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\ddot{x}   
) \delta t=\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{x} ) \delta t}
$$
Then my understanding is that the total time derivative of $L$ becomes
$$
 \Rightarrow\boxed{\frac{dL}{dt} =
\frac{\delta L\vert_{\text{time translation}}}{\delta t} 
=(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{x}  
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\ddot{x}   
) \delta t=\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{x} )\neq 0}
$$
$$
 \Rightarrow\boxed{
\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\dot{x} -L ) =\frac{d}{dt} H= 0
}
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian.

**2. Momentum conservation**:

In contrast, as we will see below, we have instead
$$
\boxed{\delta L\vert_{\text{space translation}}  = 0}
$$

To be more explicit,
let us think about the process that we redefine a new $L'$ such that
we assign $L(x+\delta x, \dot{x}+\delta \dot{x} ; t)$ at the space $x+\delta x$ to the new $L''$ at the time $x$:
$$
L''(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t) \equiv L(x+\delta x, \dot{x}+\delta \dot{x} ; t)
=L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta x
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x} 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
{\delta L\vert_{\text{space translation}}  \equiv L'(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)-L(x(t), \dot{x}(t); t)
=( \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta x
+ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x})}
$$
It turns out that $\delta L\vert_{\text{space translation}}=0$ in general, but *WHY*?
Also, if the system is space translational invariant, we do NOT interpret directly that the $L$ has $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$.
BUT we (Thornton-Marion) claim that
$$
\text{$\delta x$ has no explicit or implicit $t$ dependence}
$$
So $$\delta\dot{x}=0$$ and we use  $\delta L\vert_{\text{space translation}}=0$
and the EOM $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}= \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}$
to derive for any $\delta x$,
$$
\boxed{\delta L\vert_{\text{space translation}}=0 \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} =0 \Rightarrow  \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{d}{dt} p=0}
$$
which means the momentum conservation.

**My questions are on the top.**

**PLEASE try to answer my question in a fundamental level, instead of the technical level. But please be explicit in your answer.**

Comment: Related: [Noether Theorem and Energy conservation in classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451)

Comment: $\delta L = \frac{d}{dt} L$ seems pretty intuitive for me to be the variation of the Lagrangian under a time translation.