# Why did Noether use the Lagrangian for her conservation of energy theorem?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

So I know that for [Noether's conservation of energy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), the Lagrangian is used. However, I know that the Lagrangian doesn't always equal energy. So why did she use the Lagrangian and not other representatives of energy (ex. Hamiltonian) to construct her conservation of energy theorem?

Comment: Did Emmy Noether used any Lagrangians *at all*?  She was interested in continuous symmetries of differential equations IIRC.  Maybe this is better for HSM.SE?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I know that the Lagrangian doesn't always equal energy.

The Lagrangian never equals the energy, unless there is no potential $U$ so the problem is trivial.

In many cases, we can show that the energy is given by:
$$
H = T + U\;,
$$
where $T$ is the kinetic energy.

On the other hand, the Lagrangian is given by:
$$
L = T - U
$$

> So why did she use the Lagrangian

Whether or not *she* did, I don't know. But *one* would typically start from the Lagrangian equations of motion
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\;,
$$
which are a typical starting point for dynamical calculations.

Now consider the total time derivative of the Lagrangian:
$$
\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\dot x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\ddot x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\;.\qquad (1)
$$

If the system has no explicit time dependence then:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0 \qquad (2)
$$

Combining Eq (1) and (2) tells us that:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\dot x - L\right) = 0\;.
$$

Then we *define* the energy (Hamiltonian)
$$
H = \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\dot x - L\right)
$$

So, we have shown that the energy is conserved due to "time translation invariance" of the Lagrangian. It doesn't make sense to do it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

1. The very starting point of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) (NT) is an action formulation (and hence a Lagrangian), and [quasisymmetries](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) thereof.
2. Noether did not [formulate](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0503066) her theorem with only energy conservation in mind. Energy conservation (which according to NT is a consequence of time translation quasisymmetry, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451) related Phys.SE post) is just 1 possible conservation law.