# If the Lagrangian depends explicitly on time then the Hamiltonian is not conserved?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, hamiltonian

Why is the Hamiltonian not conserved when the Lagrangian has an explicit time dependence? What I mean is that it is very obvious to argue that if the Lagrangian has no an explicit time dependence $L=L(q(t),\dot{q}(t))$ then the Hamiltonian does not depend on time at all since, on-shell, the identity
\begin{equation}
\frac{d H}{dt} = -\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
must hold. However, in the case of the Lagrangian having explicit time dependence, that is $L=L(q(t),\dot{q}(t),t)$, how can you be entirely sure that the partial derivative does not vanish
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} \neq 0
\end{equation}
and, consequently, that the Hamiltonian is not conserved? In other words, how can you be sure there does not exist a Lagrangian depending explicitly on time such that the partial derivative with respect to time vanishes for all $t$ and then the Hamiltonian is conserved?

**Can you say for sure that the Hamiltonian is not conserved if the Lagrangian has explicit time dependence?** Or the implication only works for the other way around?

Comment: More on [energy conservation in classical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451).

Comment: Well, it’s certainly not conserved wrt time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> "how can you be sure there does not exist a Lagrangian depending explicitly on time such that the partial derivative with respect to time vanishes for all  "

If the question is that, it does not make much sense.  That is because "depending explicitly on time" exactly means that $\partial L/\partial t \neq 0$ somewhere.

So I assume that the question is whether or not the two conditions
$$\partial L/\partial t = 0\quad\text{everywhere}$$
and
$$\frac{dH}{dt}=0\quad\text{on every solution of the EL equations}$$
are really equivalent. It is known that the former implies the latter, but the converse implication is not so evident.

Above and henceforth,
$$H(t,q,\dot{q}) := -L(t,q,\dot{q})+ \sum_{k=1}^n \dot{q}^k 
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^k}.$$

Under natural hypotheses in Mechanics, the two conditions above are actually **equivalent** though of very different nature as $\partial L/\partial t=0$ does not know anything about the solutions of the EL equations.

If (a) the Lagrangian has standard form $$L= \sum_{h,k} a_{hk}(t,q) \dot{q}^h \dot{q}^k + \sum_{k} b_{k}(t,q)  \dot{q}^k+ c(t,q)\:,\tag{1}$$ (b) it is  jointly $C^2$, and (c) $$\det\left[\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \dot{q}^h \partial \dot{q}^k}\right] = \det [a_{hk}(t,q)]\neq 0\quad\text{everywhere}$$
(this requirement does not depend on the used coordinate patch of type $t,q,\dot{q}$)
then the Euler-Lagrange equations satisfy the a local existence and uniqueness  theorem of their solutions:

**THEOREM 1**. *With the above  conditions (a),(b),(c), given $(t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$ there is a unique solution
$$\gamma(t) = (t,q(t),\dot{q}(t)), \quad t \in I \ni t_0$$
of the E.L. equations
$$\dot{q}^k(t) = \frac{dq^k}{dt}|_{\gamma(t)}\:, \quad \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^k}|_{\gamma(t)}\right)- \frac{\partial L}{\partial q^k}|_{\gamma(t)}=0, \quad k=1,\ldots, n$$
in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $(t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$ with these initial conditions: $(t_0,q(t_0),\dot{q}(t_0))= (t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$.*

(Actually this theorem holds globally, but here the local version is sufficient.)

This theorem has the immediate corollary that answers the question:

**COROLLARY**. *With the hypotheses of theorem 1, in every coordinate patch with coordinate $t,q,\dot{q}$, these two facts are **equivalent***:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=0 \quad\text{everywhere in the said coordinate patch}\tag{A}$$
$$\frac{dH(\gamma(t))}{dt}=0\quad\text{for every (local) EL solution }\gamma=\gamma(t)\text{ in the said coordinate patch.}\tag{B}$$

**PROOF**. We know that on every solution $\gamma$
$$\frac{dH(\gamma(t))}{dt} = - \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}|_{\gamma(t)}\tag{2}\:.$$
This immediately yields (A) $\Rightarrow$ (B).  Now suppose that (B) holds true. Consider a kinetic state $(t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$ in the considered coordinate patch. There is  a solution $\gamma$ satisfying $\gamma(t_0)= (t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$. Due to (B) and (2) we also have
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}|_{t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0}=0$. Since $(t_0,q_0,\dot{q}_0)$ is generic, we have that (B) $\Rightarrow$ (A). QED

---

[Reference](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-27612-5)

Comment: A very complete answer! Then as $dH/dt=0$ (on-shell) implies that $\partial L / \partial t =0$ ( $B \Rightarrow A$, if you wish) you cannot have a case where $\partial L / \partial t \neq 0$ if the Hamiltonian is conserved (does not depend on time). Very useful, Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks. But please make clearer your question because as it stands it includes some nonsense. I *interpreted* your issue.

Comment: Sure, just point out those "nonsenses" and I will correct them, as you managed to interpret my issue