Energy conservation as a time translation symmetry
Noether's theorem says that a time translation symmetry gives rise to conservation of energy. However, my classical mechanics professor said in class that it was time reversal symmetry that gives rise to energy conservation. I am under the impression that the symmetry has to be continuous for Noether's theorem to apply. What am I missing here? Can someone please elaborate?

Maybe they just misspoke. You should ask them for clarification directly

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451
