# Symmetry modulo total derivative term in Noether's Theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I came across the proof of Noether's Theorem in [David Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf) (page 14) on QFT. He writes something like,

> We say that the transformation
>   $$\delta\phi(x) = \chi (\phi) \tag{1.34}$$
>   is a symmetry if the Lagrangian changes by a total derivative
>   $$ \delta \mathcal{L} = \partial_{\mu}F^{\mu}\tag{1.35}$$
>   for some set of functions $F^\mu(\phi)$.

What is the intuition behind calling that a symmetry? (I do follow the math of how we get a current vanishing after we take its derivative)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that on-shell the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ changes by a total divergence term$^1$
$$ \delta{\cal L}~\approx~d_{\mu} j^{\mu},\tag{A}$$
where
$$j^{\mu}~:=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\delta_0\phi+{\cal L}\delta x^{\mu}\tag{B}$$
is the bare Noether current. The intuition is that on-shell there cannot be any bulk term on the RHS of eq. (A), only a boundary term. Therefore if the infinitesimal transformation $\delta$ is only a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) [rather than a strict symmetry] of the Lagrangian density [that is: Tong's off-shell eq. (1.35) is satisfied], then we can still obtain an on-shell continuity equation
$$\begin{align} d_{\mu} J^{\mu}~\stackrel{(D)}{=}~~~&d_{\mu} (j^{\mu}- F^{\mu})\cr
~=~~~&d_{\mu} j^{\mu}-d_{\mu} F^{\mu}\cr ~\stackrel{(A)+(1.35)}{\approx}&~\delta{\cal L}-\delta{\cal L}\cr
~=~~~&0\end{align} \tag{C} $$
by defining the following full Noether current
$$ J^{\mu}~:=~j^{\mu}-F^{\mu}.\tag{D}$$
In other words, we can always compensate for not having a strict symmetry.

The conserved full [Noether charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is then defined as
$$Q(t)~:=~\int_V\! d^3x~ J^0(x,t) \tag{E}$$
by a standard argument.

--

$^1$ The $\approx$ sign means here equality modulo the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation), i.e. on-shell.