# Noether identities and the relativistic point particle

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

I am trying to better understand Noether identities, i.e. relations between equations of motion in the presence of gauge symmetries for the example of the relativistic point particle.

Formally, a Noether identity arises because the variation of an action leading to an equation of motion requires identical manipulations as the variation under a gauge symmetry. Thus, if an action is invariant under a gauge symmetry, we have the relation

$$
\delta_g S[\phi] = \int d^nx\,\frac{\delta L}{\delta \phi}\, \delta_g\phi = 0,\tag{1}
$$
where $\phi$ is a generic field, $\delta_g$ the variation under a gauge symmetry and $\delta L/\delta \phi$ is the equation of motion for the field $\phi$. Substituting the variation and isolating the (continuous) variation parameter then results in the constraint.

However, I cannot make sense of it applying this logic to the action of the relativistic point particle
$$
S[x] = m \int d\tau \sqrt{-\dot{x}_\mu \dot{x}^\mu}.\tag{2}
$$
The gauge symmetry here is parametrization invariance $\tau \to \tau'$ or infinitesimally
$$
\delta \tau = \varepsilon(\tau),\tag{3}
$$
for $\varepsilon$ an arbitrary (continous and monotonous) function. Calculating the variation on the coordinates gives
$$
\delta x^\mu = - \dot{x}^\mu \varepsilon.\tag{4}
$$
Correspondingly, the Noether identity reads
$$
0 = \delta S[x] =  m \int d\tau\,\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{\dot{x}_\mu}{\sqrt{- \dot{x}^2}} \right) \delta x^\mu \\
= -m \int d\tau\,\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{\dot{x}_\mu}{\sqrt{- \dot{x}^2}} \right) \dot{x}^\mu \varepsilon,\tag{5}
$$
i.e.
$$ 
\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \frac{\dot{x}_\mu}{\sqrt{- \dot{x}^2}} \right) \dot{x}^\mu = 0.\tag{6}
$$
However, I find the result hard to interpret as the relation seems to be completely arbitrary.
Can anyone maybe expand on the interpretation of this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Noether identity now, the interpretation is of course immediately clear.

We can multiply equation (6) of my question with $2 m^2 / \sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}$, and identify the two terms as the relativistic momenta. This then amounts to saying that
$$
2\frac{d}{d\tau} \left( p_\mu\right) p^\mu = 0 \implies \frac{d}{d\tau}\left(p^2\right) = 0.
$$
This is of course simply the on-shell-condition of relativity
$$
p^2 + m^2 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

1. More generally, an infinitesimal gauge [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451)
   $$\delta q^k(t)~=~\int\! dt^{\prime}~ R^k(t,t^{\prime})\epsilon(t^{\prime})\tag{3.5a}$$
   of an action functional $S[q]$,
   $$\begin{align} \text{possible}&\text{ boundary terms}\cr
   ~=~&\delta S\cr
   ~=~&\sum_k\int\! dt\int\! dt^{\prime}~\frac{\delta S}{\delta q^k(t)} R^k(t,t^{\prime})\epsilon(t^{\prime})\cr
   ~+~&\text{possible boundary terms}\end{align}\tag{3.6a}$$
   leads to an off-shell Noether identity
   $$ \sum_k\int\! dt~\frac{\delta S}{\delta q^k(t)} R^k(t,t^{\prime})~=~0, \tag{3.6b}$$
   cf. [Noether's 2nd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem) and e.g. Ref. 1.
2. The Noether identity (3.6b) can be interpreted as *the EOMs are perpendicular to the gauge quasisymmetry.*
3. The Noether identity (3.6b) is a generalization of OP's last eq. (6) with the following change of notation
   $$t~\to~\tau, \qquad q^k~\to~x^{\mu}, \qquad R^k(t,t^{\prime})~\to~-\dot{x}^{\mu}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}).$$

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; eqs. (3.5a) + (3.6a) + (3.6b).