# Gauge invariance for Lagrangian of charged particle in EM field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, gauge-invariance

Naively, we can conjecture that Lagrangian of charged particle in EM field is
$$L = \frac{1}{2}m \mathbf{v}^2 - q\varphi\tag{1}$$
where $\varphi$ is scalar potential. But it is known that this is not true and under gauge transform
$$\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{A} + \nabla \chi, \quad \varphi \rightarrow \varphi - \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t}.\tag{2}$$
This Lagrangian transforms like
$$L \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}m \mathbf{v}^2 - q\varphi + q\frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t}.\tag{3}$$
I think this does not affect underlying physics because the last term is total derivative wrt time and in terms of action, total derivative of some function doesn't give anything.

True Lagrangian of given system is
$$L = \frac{1}{2}m \mathbf{v}^2 + q\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A} - q\varphi\tag{4}$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector potential. Under the same transformation, this Lagrangian transforms like
$$L \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}m \mathbf{v}^2 + q\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A} - q\varphi  + q\frac{d\chi}{dt}.\tag{5}$$
The last term is also total derivative wrt time which does not give anything when we compute action.

1. Under which gauge we treat this Lagrangian?
2. And can we say that this Lagrangian is gauge invariant?

I know that the first Lagrangian (1) can't give us Lorentz force but second one (4) can do.

Comment: The second Lagrangian (without the $d\chi/dt$ term) is fine in any gauge. The term proportional to  $d\chi/dt$ is superfluous and can by omitted. Lagrangian in general need not be gauge invariant, and this one isn't, unless one keeps the superfluous term to intentionally define gauge invariant Lagrangian, for what there is no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here $A^{\mu}=(\phi,{\bf A})$ is an arbitrary background gauge field.
2. The gauge transformation (2) is a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the action/Lagrangian (4).