# Gauge-fixing condition invariant under auxiliary gauge transformation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

In quantum gravity one usually splits the metric $g= \bar{g}+h$ into a background field $\bar{g}$ and a fluctuation field $h$. In order to obtain a propagator one has to gauge fix the action (e.g. Einstein-Hilbert) which breaks the gauge symmetry
$$h\rightarrow h+\mathcal{L}g$$
$$\bar{g}\rightarrow \bar{g}$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative.
However, one can choose now the gauge fixing such that it is invariant under
$$h\rightarrow h+\mathcal{L}h$$
$$\bar{g}\rightarrow \bar{g} +\mathcal{L}\bar{g}.$$
My problem is now that I don’t see why for example the de-Donder gauge condition
$$ F_\mu[\bar{g},h]=\bar{\nabla}^\nu h_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\bar{\nabla}_\mu h $$
is invariant under the latter transformation.
References:

1. J. Pawlowski, M. Reichert [Quantum gravity: A fluctuating point of view](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10353) (eq. 46)
2. N. Christiansen [From the Quark-Gluon Plasma to Quantum Gravity](https://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/19254/1/Dissertation_Christiansen.pdf) (p. 35)

Comment: Note the difference between the transformation you wrote and (4.21) in your second reference.

Comment: @TimRias the transformation I wrote is just $\mathcal{G}+\mathcal{\bar{G}}$ in the second reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. The (infinitesimal) background gauge transformation is
   $$\begin{align} 
   \delta_B\bar{g}_{\mu\nu} ~=~& {\cal L}_X\bar{g}_{\mu\nu},\cr
   \delta_Bh_{\mu\nu} ~=~& {\cal L}_Xh_{\mu\nu},
   \end{align} \tag{46} $$
   where $X$ is an (infinitesimal) vector field and ${\cal L}_X$ denotes the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative).
2. More generally,
   $$ \delta_Bf\left(\bar{g}_{\mu\nu},\partial_{\lambda}\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}, \ldots; h_{\mu\nu},\partial_{\lambda}h_{\mu\nu}, \ldots\right)~=~{\cal L}_Xf\left(\bar{g}_{\mu\nu},\partial_{\lambda}\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}, \ldots; h_{\mu\nu},\partial_{\lambda}h_{\mu\nu}, \ldots\right),$$
   at least for [differential geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) objects.
3. The de-Donder gauge covector $F_{\mu}$ in eq. (7) is not invariant but transforms as
   $$ \delta_B F_{\mu}~=~{\cal L}_X F_{\mu}~=~X[F_{\mu}]+\partial_{\mu}X^{\nu}F_{\nu}.$$
4. The gauge-fixing Lagrangian [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) term
   $$ \rho~=~-\frac{1}{2\xi}\sqrt{|\bar{g}|} F_{\mu} \bar{g}^{\mu\nu}F_{\nu} \tag{6}$$
   is not strictly invariant but transforms by a total spacetime derivative
   $$\delta_B\rho~=~{\cal L}_X\rho~=~\rho{\rm div}_{\rho} X~=~d_{\mu}(\rho X^{\mu}). $$
5. One of the main features of the [background field method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_field_method) is that the background gauge transformation $\delta_B$ is a gauge [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the full gauge-fixed action.

References:

1. J.M. Pawlowski & M. Reichert, *Quantum gravity: a fluctuating point of view,* [arXiv:2007.10353](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10353).

Comment: Thank you! So the crucial point is that the background transformations treat the fluctuation and the background field on an equal footing which has the effect that  a contraction of an arbitrary tensor (which transforms under the background transformation) and the fluctuation field is invariant?

Comment: Not strictly invariant, as mentioned in the answer.